# What is the dictionary form of 깁니다?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, verb-endings, verb

I'm learning on Duolingo, and the sentence is 영화가 깁니다. I also use a Memrise deck to help me remember the words, but I always put verbs in their dictionary form. To make sure I'm using the right dictionary form, I look the verb up on Wiktionary. I did so with 깁니다, and assumed it would be 기다, but Wiktionary doesn't have a page for that. Instead it has a page for 길다, also meaning "to be long," but with 기다 listed under 'Alternative forms.'

Is 기다 the same as 길다?

Which is more common, and are they conjugated differently?

Would 길다 be 길습니다 rather than 깁니다?

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: 기다 is different from 길다. [깁니다 is correct](https://www.koreanwikiproject.com/wiki/%E3%84%B9_irregular_verbs).

Comment: The dictionary form is 길다. It is never used in the form 기다 by itself. Interestingly, 길다(long) and 기다(crawl) can both take the form 깁니다.

Comment: Note that 깁다(stitch) can also take the form 깁니다.

Comment: @Dannyu NDos wouldn't it be 깁습니다 in that case?

Comment: Welp. Forget about me. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

깁습니다 is from 깁다 which means to stitch or sew. 깁니다 is from the irregular verb 길다 (dictionary or infinitive form) and it means to be long.There is no such word as 길습니다. 깁니다 is declarative present formal high same as 합니다 from the dictionary form, 하다. The only difference between the 2 is that 길다 is irregular and 하다 is regular. Also, neither verb has a ~습니다 form in the present tense. Some verbs do have the~ 습니다 form in the declarative present formal high: 먹다 (to eat) is an example. 그 사함은 야채를 먹습니다 - The man eats vegetables.